# c#: search in string array and get specific string value

Tags: c#, xml, string

I want to search through an element value in xml file and get the specific string out of it. For instance, I have the following element value in my xml file:

```
<Content>Shape="Rectangle" Tooltip="data" StrokeThickness="2" Tag="default" </Content>
```

Now I want to read this `Content` and get `Tooltip` value as my resulted string, that should give me "data". I want something like:

```
string restuledString = Tooltip.value
```

How to do it?

Update:

This is the full xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Topologies>
  <ConfigurationItems>
    <ConfigurationItem Label="Default Tag">
      <Attribute Name="display_lable" Label="Display Label" Type="clas java.lang.String" Value="Default Tag" />
      <Attribute Name="MemorySize" Label="MemorySize" Type="class java.lang.Integer" Value="Default Tag" />
      <Attribute Name="Description" Label="Description" Type="class java.lang.String" Value="SunOS" />
      <Attribute Name="DiscoveredModel" Label="DiscoveredModel" Type="class java.lang.String" Value="Oracle Corporation sun4v SPARC T5-4" />
      <X>289</X>
      <Y>108.53999999999999</Y>
      <Width>130</Width>
      <Height>117</Height>
      <ID>ed56efb4-6bdd-4dc7-8b79-db5e9b8484f1</ID>
      <zIndex>0</zIndex>
      <IsGroup>false</IsGroup>
      <ParentID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ParentID>
      <Content>&lt;Rectangle StrokeThickness="2" Tag="Default Thread Tag" ToolTip="data" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:dd="clr-namespace:DiagramDesigner;assembly=ADAX_GUI"&gt;&lt;Rectangle.Style&gt;&lt;Style TargetType="Rectangle"&gt;&lt;Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style TargetType="Rectangle"&gt;&lt;Style.Resources&gt;&lt;ResourceDictionary /&gt;&lt;/Style.Resources&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.RenderTransform"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;SkewTransform AngleX="-15" AngleY="0" CenterX="50" CenterY="25" /&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Fill"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1"&gt;&lt;LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops&gt;&lt;GradientStop Color="#FFFAFBE9" Offset="0" /&gt;&lt;GradientStop Color="#FFFFA500" Offset="1" /&gt;&lt;/LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops&gt;&lt;/LinearGradientBrush&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Stroke"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;SolidColorBrush&gt;#FFD69436&lt;/SolidColorBrush&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.StrokeThickness"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Double&gt;1&lt;/s:Double&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.StrokeLineJoin"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;x:Static Member="PenLineJoin.Round" /&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Stretch"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;x:Static Member="Stretch.Fill" /&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.IsHitTestVisible"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Boolean&gt;False&lt;/s:Boolean&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Boolean&gt;True&lt;/s:Boolean&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;/Style&gt;&lt;/Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style.Resources&gt;&lt;ResourceDictionary /&gt;&lt;/Style.Resources&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.StrokeDashArray"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;DoubleCollection&gt;1.5 0.7&lt;/DoubleCollection&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;/Style&gt;&lt;/Rectangle.Style&gt;&lt;dd:DesignerItem.DragThumbTemplate&gt;&lt;ControlTemplate&gt;&lt;Rectangle Name="ThreadShape" Width="250" Height="150"&gt;&lt;Rectangle.Style&gt;&lt;Style TargetType="Rectangle"&gt;&lt;Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style TargetType="Rectangle"&gt;&lt;Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style TargetType="Rectangle"&gt;&lt;Style.Resources&gt;&lt;ResourceDictionary /&gt;&lt;/Style.Resources&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.RenderTransform"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;SkewTransform AngleX="-15" AngleY="0" CenterX="50" CenterY="25" /&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Fill"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1"&gt;&lt;LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops&gt;&lt;GradientStop Color="#FFFAFBE9" Offset="0" /&gt;&lt;GradientStop Color="#FFFFA500" Offset="1" /&gt;&lt;/LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops&gt;&lt;/LinearGradientBrush&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Stroke"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;SolidColorBrush&gt;#FFD69436&lt;/SolidColorBrush&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.StrokeThickness"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Double&gt;1&lt;/s:Double&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.StrokeLineJoin"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;x:Static Member="PenLineJoin.Round" /&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Stretch"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;x:Static Member="Stretch.Fill" /&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.IsHitTestVisible"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Boolean&gt;False&lt;/s:Boolean&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Boolean&gt;True&lt;/s:Boolean&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;/Style&gt;&lt;/Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style.Resources&gt;&lt;ResourceDictionary /&gt;&lt;/Style.Resources&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.StrokeDashArray"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;DoubleCollection&gt;1.5 0.7&lt;/DoubleCollection&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;/Style&gt;&lt;/Style.BasedOn&gt;&lt;Style.Resources&gt;&lt;ResourceDictionary /&gt;&lt;/Style.Resources&gt;&lt;Setter Property="UIElement.IsHitTestVisible"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;s:Boolean&gt;True&lt;/s:Boolean&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Fill"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;SolidColorBrush&gt;#00FFFFFF&lt;/SolidColorBrush&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;Setter Property="Shape.Stroke"&gt;&lt;Setter.Value&gt;&lt;SolidColorBrush&gt;#00FFFFFF&lt;/SolidColorBrush&gt;&lt;/Setter.Value&gt;&lt;/Setter&gt;&lt;/Style&gt;&lt;/Rectangle.Style&gt;&lt;/Rectangle&gt;&lt;/ControlTemplate&gt;&lt;/dd:DesignerItem.DragThumbTemplate&gt;&lt;/Rectangle&gt;</Content>
    </ConfigurationItem>
  </ConfigurationItems>
  <Connections />
</Topologies>
```

Comment: Have you mis-typed the XML? The `<Content>` looks like the attributes should be inside the `<Content>` tag

Comment: Post the full XML or a complete sample, how are we supposed to advise with only a single node?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on msdn about parsing xml..

Comment: Is XML like this or `<Content Shape="Rectangle" Tooltip="data" StrokeThickness="2" Tag="default" />`

Comment: Is this the first Content Node? Are there multiple? What if the Tooltip isn't there?

Comment: The problem here is not how to parse the xml since I know how to parse it. But I want to get the specific string after a pre-defined string tag, like "Tooltip" here. Thank you.

Comment: it seems that there is some kind of misformatted xml in your content of the content tag look: "/&gt;&lt;" i guess actually is is ><

Comment: I am a new learner, and using WPF with C#. The output xml file is saved in this manner, I don't know whether it is standard or not since I am a fresh.

Comment: being a fresh new learner should not prevent you from using your brain ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to just parse the text in your xml node (which you'll have to get on your own since you didn't provide any info about xml structure), you could do it the nasty way:

```
string yourNodeValue = @"Shape=""Rectangle"" Tooltip=""data"" StrokeThickness=""2"" Tag=""default""";
string output;
var keysAndValues = yourNodeValue.Split(' ').Select (nv => nv.Trim())
foreach(var keyValue in keysAndValues)
{
    var pair = keyValue.Split('=');
    if(pair[0] == "Tooltip")
    {
        output = pair[1].Trim('"');
        break;
    }
}
```

However, I assumed there'll always be `key="value"` format preserved, no spaces between.
Or you could just use a regex groupping pattern `Shape=\"(\w+)\"`

Comment: I tried your code, and it gives me exactly what I want. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var xml = "<Content> Shape=\"Rectangle\" Tooltip=\"data\" StrokeThickness=\"2\" Tag=\"default\" </Con" +
"tent>";


using(var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
{
    while(xmlReader.Read())
    {
        var regex = "Tooltip=\"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\"";
        var match  = Regex.Match(xmlReader.Value, regex).Value.Replace("Tooltip=\"", "").Replace("\"", "");

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(match))
        {
            var restuledString = match;         
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You have a deep look into your file you would probably recognise that it is a xml structure inside your Content-tag.
you could read it like this and then load it as xml content:

```
var xmlfilecontent = IO.File.ReadAllText("yourfilename");        
    xmlfilecontent = xmlfilecontent.Replace("&gt;&lt;", ">\n<");
    xmlfilecontent = xmlfilecontent.Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&gt;", ">");
    IO.File.WriteAllText("yourfilenamel", xmlfilecontent);
```